# cant enable UFW firewall

Tags: server, firewall, ufw

I am trying to set up a code-server on my ubuntu 22.04.
However I came to the realisation that my firewall wasnt enabled and tried enabling it using the instructions on this other thread : https://superuser.com/questions/590600/ufw-is-active-but-not-enabled-why.

When checking status of the firewall I am told it is inactive.
when doing sudo ufw enable I am given this error message.:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ufw/util.py", line 427, in under_ssh
    ppid = get_ppid(pid)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ufw/util.py", line 419, in get_ppid
    ppid = open(name).readlines()[0].split(')')[1].split()[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/ufw", line 138, in <module>
    not ui.continue_under_ssh():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ufw/frontend.py", line 901, in continue_under_ssh
    if self.backend.do_checks and ufw.util.under_ssh(): # pragma: no cover
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ufw/util.py", line 457, in under_ssh
    return under_ssh(ppid)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ufw/util.py", line 457, in under_ssh
    return under_ssh(ppid)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ufw/util.py", line 457, in under_ssh
    return under_ssh(ppid)
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ufw/util.py", line 434, in under_ssh
    raise ValueError(err_msg)
ValueError: Couldn't find parent pid for '2182'
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `apt policy ufw`. Are you running this on Windows Subsystem for Linux? The error looks a lot like [ufw crashes in wsl2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ufw/+bug/2015645)